# TensorFlow lite classification model;{1,1,1,3}

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, image-classification, preprocessing, java

How can I initialize and insert images into this classification model;  what is meant by {1,1,1,3} according to my parameters it should be {1,size,size,3} please help

try {
Firstclass model = Firstclass.newInstance(context);

```
// Creates inputs for reference.
TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

// Runs model inference and gets result.
Firstclass.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close();
```

} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Handle the exception
}